# swap function in recursive string permutations

Tags: algorithm, permutation

[HERE](http://www.divye.in/2011/06/printing-all-permutations-of-string.html) is the recursive string permutation solution that I am referring to. I understand that algorithm but not able to understand how code is making it work. As in how two swaps are working here.

```
char * full_string;
void permute(char * str, int length) {
    if(length == 0) {
        printf(“%s\n”, full_string);
        return;
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            swap(str[0], str[i]);
            permute(str+1, length-1);
            swap(str[0], str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for my poor painting. The algorithm basically run like this:

```
                                 ABC
             /                    |                     \
        swap(A,A)              swap(A,B)              swap(A,C)
           /                      |                       \
         ABC                     BAC                      CBA
    /         \               /       \                /       \
swap(B,B)   swap(B,C)    swap(A,A)  swap(A,C)    swap(B,B)   swap(B,A)
  /             \           /           \            /           \
ABC             ACB       BAC            BCA        CBA          CAB
```

Remember `permute` generate all permutations of last `length` elements, so you swap each element with first element and go next, this way you will get all permutations.

Comment: Thanks justmscs .. it is the third time you have helped me out. :) Seems like both of us are preparing for interviews after ms in cs :P ... Can we be friends ? as in that way we may help each other more proactively :)

Comment: and do you have any thoughts on time complexity of this.

Comment: It's a pleasure. SO is a fantastic place, I have learned a lot in here. And the complexity is `n!` since a string of length `n` has `n!` permutations(if characters are unique).

Answer (score 0):

Will, the code is not to complex if you know c/c++.

Lets start with the else clause, as it's the main functional part of the function.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    swap(str[0], str[i]);
    permute(str+1, length-1);
    swap(str[0], str[i]);
```

The for loop you should understand - it's just like in java.

str is a char array (actually a pointer, but for many cases they are the same). so `str[0]` is the first element of the char array.

The main part that will confuse Java programmers in this code is `str+1` - what does it mean to add one to an array? Here comes the fact str is a pointer and not an array - c/c++ supports [pointers arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#C_arrays). adding one to a pointer (basically) means any future references will be denoted by one. e.g. `s[1]` after adding is equal to `s[2]` before.

I think after these explanations, the code should be clear.

Comment: No it is not. I did not understand the logic behind two swaps. I know that much of C for that matter. Thanks for replying though

Comment: The logic of two swaps is to swap, then swap back, so the string at the end doesn't change for the next routine.

Comment: Can you please explain with an example .. like "ABC" .. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
char * full_string; // String is defined... hopefully you get this
void permute(char * str, int length) {
    if(length == 0) { // if the length to permute is 0, string should be as-is. This is the base case of the recursion.
        printf(“%s\n”, full_string);
        return;
    } else { // Otherwise... (Recursive case)
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            swap(str[0], str[i]); // Swap the first character with the i-th character
            permute(str+1, length-1); // Get all permutations with the i-th character as the first character
            swap(str[0], str[i]); // Get the original string back for the next loop
        }
    }
}
```

The hardest part to understand is the recursive bit. Try tracing out how it would work with a simple example and you should see how it works.

Essentially for a string `'abc'` to find all permutations you want all the permutations of `'a' + permutations('bc')`, `'b' + permutations('ac')`, and `'c' + permutations('ab')`

Then (for example) for the case of `a + permutations('bc')` this breaks down to finding `ab + permutations('c')` and `'ac' + permutations('b')`, which on the next recursive calls just gets you `'abc'` and `'acb'`.

Then the same process is done for the cases when `'b'` is your first character and `'c'` is your first character.

Hopefully you can see how this same process can break down a larger string into finding the permutations of the first character + all permutations of the remaining characters